# How to debug methods from Reference Classes?

Tags: r, reference-class

How to debug a call like getFields? I tried `library(debug); mtrace(AB.setFields)` but nothing happend.

Besides there are some better ways to define AB.setFields?

```
AB.getFields<-function(){
  return(list(name,var2))
}
AB.setFields<-function(fields){
  namevar<-names(fields)
  for(i in 1:length(fields)) do.call("<<-",list(namevar[i],fields[[i]]))
}
AB <- setRefClass("AB", fields=c(name="character",
                                 var2="factor"),
                        methods=list(getFields=AB.getFields
                                    ,setFields=AB.setFields)
                  )
a<-AB(name="abc",var2=factor(LETTERS[1:3]))
a$getFields()
fields<-list(name="aaa",var2=factor(1:3))
a$setFields(fields)
a$getFields()
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are trying to use "." in a manner that is not supported by R syntactic conventions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to call the `trace` method of the instance object.

```
a$trace("setFields")
```

---

This is the implementation that you want for the `setFields` method.

```
AB.setFields <- function(...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  fieldNames <- names(dots)
  for(i in seq_along(dots)) 
  {
    assign(fieldNames[[i]], dots[[i]], attr(.self, ".xData"))
  }
}

a$setFields(name="aaa",var2=factor(1:3))
```

---

There's probably some syntactic sugar I've missed to make this prettier, but to get all your fields, you can use

```
AB.getFields <- function(){
  mget(
    names(.refClassDef@fieldClasses), 
    envir = attr(.self, ".xData")
  )
}
```

Comment: Thx, is it also possible to call all member variables at one time from the environment `attr(.self, ".xData")`? Or is the proper way to do this `AB.getFields<-function(){
  return(list(name=name,var2=var2))
}`?

Comment: Hi, could you please help again, I tried to find out how to trace trace the initialize function, if I instantiate a new object like AB$new(...). I tried AB$trace("initialize") but it doesnt work.

Comment: @Klaus: You need to explicitly define an `initialize` method before you can trace it.